# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lru' when running web3 python code

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror, web3py, lru

So I'm trying to run web3 in a python environment. I successfully installed the web3 module.
When I run the program it outputs

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lru'

So after researching, the common solution to the problem is to run this command:

```
pip install lru
```

This gave me a bizarre error with lots of red and yellow lettering:

[Bizarre lru error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzhYJ.png)

After looking at all the red error lettering. It's saying there's a **raise KeyError, key** pointing at the command,

It also shows 2 other errors after that:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lru (from versions: 0.1)

> ERROR: No matching distribution found for lru

I tried another install solution.
pip install lru-dict

> Requirement already satisfied: lru-dict in C:\Users\ ....

So I do not know where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

This issue happened because the python version I built my python environment in, isn't supported by lru. Be default my environment is running python 3.9.5. So it seems I need to be running an older version of python to get it to work.

I simply created a new python environment and set the python version to an earlier version. So now the lru issue went away.